FilePath on Vb.net
I've created a console application which sends email, that email will attach an html file. The html file is in the project. Now I need to do this function File.ReadAllText(), I have to point the directory of the file here. I can't seem to point it properly as it directs me to the \bin\debug\File.html directory, I should be out of the bin folder, as the html file is where the .sln file can be found.  I just define this on the App.Config file like add a key and value. But that doesn't work. So maybe someone can point me to the right answer.
For example
EmailSolution Folder
--> bin folder
--> obj folder
--> .sln file
--> file.hmtl
-->etc...

put it into the bin/Debug or RELeASE\ .... where your exe is and the  use application startup path

What IDE (editor) are you using? VS, VS Code, etc.

You need to learn how your environment can deploy the File.html with the EXE.


Solution Explorer > Right-click the Project > Add Existing Item... > Select the HTML file
Solution Explorer > Right-Click the File > Properties > Copy To Output Directory > Copy Always

This will deploy your HTML file with your app.
